# Load specific folder before other and rest process should be same in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, autoload

```
.
|-- app
|   |-- assets
|   |   |-- images
|   |   ........
|   |   ........
|   |-- controllers
|   |   ........
|   |   ........
|   |-- helpers
|   |   ........
|   |   ........
|   |-- mailers
|   |   ........
|   |   ........
|   |-- models
|   |   |--comments
|   |   |--new_events # Inherites `events`
|   |   |--old_events # Taking name to follow the sequence by name
|   |   |--posts
|   |   *-- comment.rb
|   |   *-- new_event.rb
|   |   *-- old_event.rb
|   |   *-- post.rb
|   |   ........
|   |   ........
```

**Represents:**

```
    `|--` : Folder
    `*--` : File
```

**Note:**

```
`new_events` -> Folder which also contains other folders and files
`old_events` -> Folder which also contains other folders and files
```

Both folders are somehow identical, `new_folder`'s files inherites same `name` file from `old_events` to get the `properties`.

`new_events` inherites `old_events`. But `Rails` auto-loading, loads `new_events` first and it inherites `old_events` so that cause issue because it is not yet loaded.

**Tried:**

I have tried to load `old_events` before `new_evensts` but `old_events` also inherites some other `classes` like `old_event.rb` etc.

In `application.rb` file, I have added below:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/old_events/)
```

but that even causes issue that, `Rails` tried load it first but it also has dependenices. It seems blocker to me.

**Expected:**

I want the loading process should everything as ususal but it should load `old_events` folder before `new_folder`. I can't change the name so it would appear before.

Or a way by which I load `new_events` in the last so that `events` would load before and rest of the models as well?

Comment: Not entirely sure if it'll fix your case, but it have you tried to sprinkle in some [require_dependency](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#require-dependency)?

Comment: @SimpleLime - Yep, but it will cause another dependency issue. I want something like `callback` (wierd) like `new_events` should load after `old_events`, and rest should work like existing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, `autoload_paths` works here You can do like this:

in `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

and keep the right naming convention in `lib`.

in `lib/test.rb`

```
class Test
end
```

in `lib/test/subtest.rb`

```
class Test::SubTest
end
```

For more understand go through this links [blog](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/rails-3-autoload-modules-and-classes-in-production/) or [articles](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4661-The-require-and-load-path-in-Ruby)